# How to get index of smallest value from list

Tags: java, android

I want to get the index of smallest value from ArrayList of String type

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add("7.01");
list.add("12.01")
list.add("9.00");
list.add("8.1");
```

I am getting those above value from server.

1. Either tell me what is the best way to add it.
2. Or how to get smallest value index by above ways.
   Thanks

Comment: What have you tried already? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: You should take a look at [ask]

Comment: Also, this question must have been asked a thousand times before. Have you searched?

Comment: Have you tried looping and doing a comparison. Or just google "find smallest number in array"

Comment: you mean smallest value ?

Comment: @JoeC: "How to get index of smallest value from list" - read the label

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your list to type of Double, parse your strings to double and simply get the minimum of your array afterwards:

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(parseDouble("7.01"));
list.add(parseDouble("12.01"));
list.add(parseDouble("9.00"));
list.add(parseDouble("8.1"));

//System.out.println(Collections.min(list));

int indexOfMinimum = list.indexOf(Collections.min(list));
```

Comment: You have nice idea, but incorrect code. Generics can't hold primitive type, we need wrapper there so not `<int>` but `<Integer>`, but even then `Integer` can't hold fractions, you need `<Double>`.

Comment: @ModularSynth lol - sorry :-D I just woke up^^

Comment: Firstly, you can not declare int as generic type. Secondly, its not Integer, it is a Float. So it should be ArrayList<Float>

Comment: BTW this returns minimal *value*, not *index* of that value.

Comment: `list.indexOf()` method should return the index of the first element that matches the minimum we got by `Collections.min()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(parseDouble("7.01"));
list.add(parseDouble("12.01"));
list.add(parseDouble("9.00"));
list.add(parseDouble("8.1"));
```

int indexOfMinimum = list.indexOf(Collections.min(list));